# why is there an anomaly in asymptotic time and actual time for each solution?

Tags: c++, c++11, time, stl, time-complexity

I was solving this problem:-
You're given strings J representing the types of stones that are jewels, and S representing the stones you have.  Each character in S is a type of stone you have.  You want to know how many of the stones you have are also jewels.

The letters in J are guaranteed distinct, and all characters in J and S are letters. Letters are case sensitive, so "a" is considered a different type of stone from "A".

Example 1:

Input: J = "aA", S = "aAAbbbb"
Output: 3
Example 2:

Input: J = "z", S = "ZZ"
Output: 0

My logic for solution 1.

Hash the stones(unordered_map) so that we have the frequency of each type and have to find only the different stones in the given jewels once.
The find function takes o(n) for each stone n hence the time complexity is O(n^2).

```
int numJewelsInStones(string j, string s) {
        
        unordered_map<char, int>stones;
        for(char s1:s)
            ++stones[s1];
       
        auto it = stones.begin(); 
        int count = 0;
        for(it = stones.begin(); it != stones.end(); ++it)
        {
            char s1 = it->first;
            if(j.find(s1) != string::npos)
                count += it->second;
            
        }
        return count;
```

So i thought that o(n^2) was too much and decided to try to furthur optimise this.
So i hashed the jewels as well by putting it into an unordered_set. That way, all duplicated are removed and it takes o(1) time to find a stone in it.
So, for each stone it takes o(1) time and hence time complexity becomes o(n).

```
int numJewelsInStones(string j, string s) {
        
        unordered_map<char, int>stones;
        for(char s1:s)
            ++stones[s1];
        unordered_set<char>uset(j.begin(), j.end()); 
        auto it = stones.begin(); 
        int count = 0;
        for(it = stones.begin(); it != stones.end(); ++it)
        {
            char s1 = it->first;
            
            if(uset.find(s1) != uset.end())
                count += it->second;
                
        }
        return count;
```

The problem arises here- when i used the clock function from time.h to measure the run time 
for solution 1 i got 0.000126 units of time 
for solution 2 i got 0.000145 units of time 
 which does not makes sense when the first one is o(n^2) and the second one is o(n).

btw, this is my code for getting the time-

```
int main()
{
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    Solution ob;
    string j = "aA", s = "aAAbbbb";
    cout << ob.numJewelsInStones(j, s) << endl;
    cout << (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*Is anyone able to explain this anomaly to me?*

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Size and time seem much to small to draw a conclusion

Comment: @cigien no i am not

Comment: Then comparing the results is basically pointless. Compile with optimizations, and decently large inputs.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Test your algorithm with sufficiently large n

For small values of n, **cache performance** is more dominant. `unordered_set` is implemented as a hash-table in C++, hence lookups involve traversing pointers (here, I assume that you know how hash-maps are implemented). Traversing pointers means reading from different parts of the memory. This affects the cache performance, as the next object that the hash-map wants to check is very likely not in the cache, and would have to be fetched from a higher memory level.
Arrays on the other hand display [*locality of reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). This makes effective use of the cache, hence you achieve better performance with arrays on small examples.

Time complexity of an algorithm is used to see how well your algorithm scales with size. A `O(n^2)` algorithm might perform better than a `O(n)` algorithm on smaller inputs (as it does in this example), but on *sufficiently* large input, an algorithm with lower time complexity is bound to perform better.

Comment: oh i see. So, basically its O(1) time to search an element because each element is hashed by a hash function but to actually retrieve it from memory is where it acts comparatively slower as compared to arrays(arrays have locality of reference).

Comment: Yes. Also, if you want better cache performance, you can perhaps implement your hash-set in [open-addressing scheme](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashing-set-3-open-addressing/). This will give you best of both worlds. The performance will be dependent on the size of input and the size of your cache (and relative access speeds)